# What is the notation $f'(x^+) $ and $f'(x^-)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, slope

Differentiability of a function at a point $x$ is confirmed when

> $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$ exists and is finite.

But in some textbooks it is noted that a function is differentiable if $f'(x^+)$ and $f'(x^-)$ are equal and finite. I'm confused how **this** notation links with the **above** method of *derivative by first principle.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the left and right derivatives: 
$$
f'(x^+)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h,\ \ \ \ f'(x^-)=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h.
$$